# `siglongjmp` to a returned function

Tags: c, signals, setjmp

My question arises from implementing a version of the standard I/O fgets function, called tfgets, that times out and returns NULL if it does not receive an input line on standard input within 5 seconds.
A reference solution is:

```c
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sigjmp_buf buf;

void sigchild_handler(int sig) {
    puts("handler\n");
    siglongjmp(buf, 1);
}

// read with timeout
char *tfgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        sleep(5);
        printf("Child exits.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    switch (sigsetjmp(buf, 1)) {
        case 0:
            signal(SIGCHLD, sigchild_handler);
            return fgets(s, size, stream);
            break;
        case 1:
            return NULL;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    if (tfgets(buf, 1024, stdin) == NULL)
        printf("BOOM!\n");
    else
        printf("%s", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

This is implemented with `sigsetjmp` and `siglongjmp`. I noticed that when the user input something within 5 seconds, the program would behave normally and return.
The forked child process usually is still sleeping, since the main routine can not last this long. I tried to block `main()` function by adding a line of `while(1)` before return. We I try to run it, input something within 5 secs, and then let it loop. About 5 secs later, the child process should wake up and the signal handler should be executed. However, the `siglongjmp` doesn't work.
In this senario, `tfgets` has already returned but `sigsetjmp` is in it. In man page for sigsetjmp, NOTES section, it says:

> If the function which called setjmp() returns before longjmp() is called, the  behavior  is  undefined.   Some kind of subtle or unsubtle chaos is sure to result.

My question:
Is the behavior that the long jump is not taken is actually **not guaranteed to behave in this way**?
If so, how could I fix that?
Thanks a lot~

Comment: setjmp + longjmp have a whole lot of undefined behavior associated with them. Whatever setjmp actually stacks isn't well-defined to begin with.

Comment: In an async signal handler, you can't use stdio or pretty much anything in the std lib. It's so restricted... avoid async signal handlers.

Comment: I'm not sure stdio functions like fgets can be reliable when a longjmp can interrupt them while they're e.g. setting locks or allocating buffers. Do you need to implement timed reads this way? Using `read` and `sigaction` and `setitimer` would be more reliable, but I don't know if you're allowed to use them.